# Reroute Django's "handle_uncaught_exception"

Tags: python, django, exception

Is there a way of catching Django's `handle_uncaught_exception` and somehow rerouting the error via views?

We use our own database backend for Django. Two important features of the backend is that we use the database to raise exceptions which we wish to percolate to the frontend, and we provide a lazy rowgetter using namedtuples.

When I use the lazy rowgetter I can't catch the custom exception, which I can do when I do a standard query. An example backtrace is as follows:

```
ERROR Internal Server Error: /api/b-r-o-k-e-n--t-o-k-e-n/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 136, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  ...lines removed...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 144, in render
    values = list(values)
  File "../xmlapi/model/model.py", line 80, in xmlapi_get_location_rota
    for i in self.foldquery(query, args, slices):
  File "../xmlapi/model/db.py", line 168, in foldquery
    self.query(querystring, args)
  File "../xmlapi/model/db.py", line 44, in wrapped_fn
    raise DBException(e.message.strip())
DBException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
 ...lines removed...
```

The advantage of the lazy rowgetter is that it is only invoked once the template starts to render (I think). The disadvantage appears to be that I can't catch the exception in the view to raise, say a `420: rate limit exceeded` error.

Because of the late evaluation, the error handler is not called:

```
    try:
        rota = self.model.xmlapi_get_location_rota (**kwargs)
    except DBException, e:
        code, message = [epart.strip() for epart in e.msg.split(':')]
        return HttpResponse(message, status=code,
                            content_type="text/plain")
```

I'd be grateful for any thoughts on trying to throw this exception earlier without having to load the whole result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an exception raised when the template is rendered, the exception can't currently be handled in Django 1.3/1.4.

It has been recommended on the django-developers list that the ability to catch a TemplateResponse exception should be added as a django feature request.

Please refer to the [Django-developers google groups email thread](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/tree/browse_frm/thread/7500ddc2106817fb/79189085e1eba778?rnum=1&_done=/group/django-developers/browse_frm/thread/7500ddc2106817fb/79189085e1eba778?tvc=1&) for more details.